# NODEJS: Send a file and data at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is what I got. It works great but I'd like to be able to send a file and data (JSON), to the client when he logs in my website. Is there any way to combine that?

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send 2 files at once. But you can embed the JSON inside the html by using a template library with `ejs`.

Answer (score 0):

A stream can send only one type of content for a request. However, depending on your Accept headers, you can send different content for different requests on the same request URL

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {      
    if(req.accepts('text/html')){
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
        return;
     }
     else if(req.accepts('application/json')){  
        res.json({'key':'value'});
        return;
     }
});
```

Here if your request header accepts `'text/html'`, it will return the index.html file. and if the request header accepts `'application/json'` it will return the JSON response.

Comment: If you want to send html and json this will not work. It will only send one or the other